Which test for Normalised quantification data between three groups
I want to compare a quantity of one variable (Number of reads assigned to Candida) between three groups (Disease 1, Disease 2 and non sick)
When I test with different methods to results are not always the same. If I use a steel or a Dunnett test (against control non sick) I get divergent results
If I use a Mann Whitney I have a significant difference altogether and with an all pairs comparison , I get again something different.
I really do not know which one to follow, could someone help ?

It should not be a surprise that these tests give you different results, because they test different statistics, with different null hypotheses.
Dunett (and the ANOVA you may have run before, but do not mention) are test of the means, with a null of equality of the means.
Mann-Whitney (and Steel, and Kruskal-Wallis, which you may have run before K-W) are tests of stochastic superiority, with a null of stochastic equality.
It is quite easy to construct examples of $X$ and $Y$ samples, where the mean of $X$ is significantly larger than $Y$ for a t-test (or ANOVA), but $Y$ is stochastically greater than $X$ for a Mann-Whitney U test (see, e.g. this post on CV).
So which test should you use? It depends on what you are interested in? What are you trying to demonstrate? Was that not established before the data was even collected?
If you are interested in the means, then run 2 2-sample Welch t-tests, with an adjusted $\alpha$ (multiple comparison correction (MCC); just use Bonferroni, i.e. $\frac \alpha 2$). For these tests, your data needs to be not too "non-normal" (and/or your sample size large enough (CLT)).
If you are interested in stochastic superiority, or if at least one of your sample is severely skewed, then use 2 Brunner-Manzel tests, again with a MCC (i.e. $\frac \alpha 2$). Why Brunner-Manzel test (BMt) and not Mann-Whitney U (MWUt)? Because BMt is to MWUt what Welch's t-test is to the standard Student's t test; it solves (or rather does not fall victim to) the Behrens-Fisher problem (i.e. it works as it should even when the variances of your 2 samples are different).
